# Why am I getting another Commit Id in output?

Tags: git

I am executing

> git branch --contains d54ede4e40364def648b30f7a8c567e1240c1225

this git command it should give me the branch name for the specified commit Id only as per my knowledge.

The output I am getting is

```
  79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83
* master
```

Can anyone tell  be why I am getting a different Commit Id in the output.

In some case for some different commit ID I am getting output as below

```
warning: refname '79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83' is ambiguous.
Git normally never creates a ref that ends with 40 hex characters
because it will be ignored when you just specify 40-hex. These refs
may be created by mistake. For example,

  git checkout -b $br $(git rev-parse ...)

where "$br" is somehow empty and a 40-hex ref is created. Please
examine these refs and maybe delete them. Turn this message off by
running "git config advice.objectNameWarning false"
  79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83
* master
```

Can anyone explain me why I am getting this type of outputs.

```
git branch -v
  79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83 79d8619 Git Check file ***
* master                                   8ca4c06 Multiple files
```

Comment: It looks like a typo in a previous command somehow created a branch *named* `79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83`. Maybe inspect your `history` to find out where it went awry. Then eventually delete the branch.

Comment: @AD7six I have updated with git branch -v. ya I have mistakenly created that branch.

Comment: @RomainValeri Can you tell me how can I know that for this particular commit id which branch I am using in this case --> git branch --contains d54ede4e40364def648b30f7a8c567e1240c1225 79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83 * master

Comment: Any number of branches can point to the same commit. What do you mean? It seems your `79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83` branch is just pointing to the commit with that exact same hash. Just delete it with `git branch -d 79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83` and (if needed) recreate the branch with the name you want with `git branch <name> 79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git branch --contains` will return the branches that contain the named commit (in other words, the branches whose tip commits are descendants of the named commit)

In your case that are two branches, `master` and a branch named `79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83` which I assume you created by mistake?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I know that for this  particular commit id which branch I am using in this case --> git branch --contains d54ede4e40364def648b30f7a8c567e1240c1225 79d86199fb35cd88829551857057e3729fddcb83
 * master